# How do I set text color?

Tags: html, css, textcolor

Title explains it all, please note I would just Google this but for some reason my computer is having a hard time connecting to the internet at the moment, so I had to write this on my phone with really awful web formatting.

EDIT: On a real computer now, to clarify I needed to set the text color of a string in an HTML document, preferably through CSS. Just something simple, like this:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  The word <whatever styling here...>RED<end styling...> should be red!
</body>`

I wasn't able to try much at the time I posted this, since my computer was having internet trouble, so I didn't really know what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 <span style="color: yourColor">your text</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

for an inline style

```
<p style="color: blue"> text here </p>
```

if you want css with classes / ids ect..
put this in css file or in a script tag on your page:

```
.textColor
{
    color: blue;
}
```

then add the class to the element

```
<p class="textColor"> text here </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="color:red;">pizza</p>
```

in html

```
p{
   color:red;
}
```

like that in css

Answer (score 0):

`<p class="attention"></p>` in your html

```
.attention{
   color:red;
}
```

in your css file, eg. my_styles.css which you include in the HEAD of your html, e.g.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_styles.css">
</head>
```

The above is if attention will appear more than once.
If it will never appear more than once you can use an id instead of a class, e.g.

`<p id="attention"></p>` in your html and

```
#attention{
   color:red;
}
```

in your css file

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
<font color='red' >your text here</font>
```

By this you can set the desired color for us text . You can also use the hexadecimal format here .

Comment: The `<font>` tag has been [depreciated for years](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp), and is not compatible with HTML 5 at all. Using [tag:CSS] is the way to go.