# Make strings colored in MFMailComposer

Tags: html, swift, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Hello everybody,

I have built the MFMailComposer in my app. Now I have inserted strings (see code) in the text to be later in the mail, which are defined by the user beforehand. Now to my question. I would like that the font color of the value of the strings in the mail should be red. How do I do that?

```
func showMailComposer() {
    
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
        return
    }
    
    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composer.setToRecipients(["E-Mail@gmail.com"])
    composer.setSubject("Bewertung Tisch 1")
    composer.setMessageBody("""
    
    Teamname:
    \(String(describing: teamname.text))
    
    Runde:
    \(String(describing: runde.text))
    
    Zeit:
    \(String(describing: zeit.text))
    
    
    Gesamtpunktzahl:
    \(String(describing: punkteGesamt.text))
    
        
    """ , isHTML: false)

    present(composer, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Use HTML tags to colors parts you want, and then `isHTML: false` => `isHTML: true`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500461/how-do-i-set-text-color ? Just "HTML + tags + text + color"?

Comment: @Larme I’m sorry. I don’t understand this... Could you maybe show me how to do that?

Comment: Did you try with adding `<p style="color:red;">pizza</p>` to you messageBody AND setting `isHTML:true` as said https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500479/1801544 ?

Comment: @Larme I was a little silly. Sorry. I meant how I do the string interpolation and how I Generally convert the content of my MessageBody to HTML (I have no idea of HTML. . . that’s why I ask)

Comment: Stop deleting your comment, redoing it, pinging me each time. I want less and less to help you... "I have no idea of HTML"? Then read about HTML. Do you expect me to code for you? It's unclear what you want, what you've tried, what's your exact issue. I think I gave you enought information to dig a little by yourself.